# Not able to download and play video files that are uploaded by an Android Emulator on an iOS physical device using VideoController in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-video-player

I simply want to play a video that I recorded and uploaded from my Android Emulator on my iOS device but for some reason, I am not able to download it using VideoContoller in Flutter. I wonder if this has something to do with the format of the video that was being uploaded by the Android Emulator or do I need to convert the uploaded video into a different format? Right now the video that I upload from my Android Emulator is in MP4 format. I am also using `VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url)` to download my file.

It stays spinning as specified in my code snippet:

```
class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String url;

  VideoPlayerScreen({Key key, this.url}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(widget.url);

    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();

    _controller.setLooping(true);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                );
              } else {
                // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
                // show spinner.
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
          Center(
              child: ButtonTheme(
                  height: 100.0,
                  minWidth: 200.0,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
                          _controller.pause();
                        } else {
                          _controller.play();
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      _controller.value.isPlaying
                          ? Icons.pause
                          : Icons.play_arrow,
                      size: 120.0,
                    ),
                  )))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the iOS device physical or a simulator? video_player is not compatible with iOS simulators. Please clarify the question and add a code sample, so we can reproduce your issue. Thanks!

Comment: I am using a physical device

Comment: are you following this tutorial? https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video also can you print the video url

Comment: Yes, I have followed that tutorial. The problem is that I am able to play other videos other than the ones that I upload from the camera of my android emulator.

Comment: If other videos are playing fine, then it's likely an issue outside of the code snippet you shared. Next steps are to double check all permissions and do code breaks or print statements to follow how far your code functions correctly. I can't help you much more without more code. (also don't forget to flutter clean and flutter doctor)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was with the video that I uploaded from my emulator's camera. When I try to upload from a real Android device this issue doesn't happen.